# Calculating mean of columns using python regular expression

Tags: python, pandas

| pcd | DCF | DDF | FFD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB106 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| AB107 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| AC200 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| AC200 | 1 | 6 | 6 |
| AC201 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| SD234 | 3 | 1 | 3 |

**Required Table**

| pcd | DCF(mean) | DDF(mean) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB106 | 0.5 | 1 |
| AB107 | 1 | 1.5 |
| AC200 | 1 | 3.33 |
| AC201 | 0.66 | 1 |
| SD234 | 3 | 1 |

**Explanation**:
For "AB106" DCF(mean), it is 0.5 (1/2), where the denominator is the number of rows starting with "AB1" and the numerator is the sum of DCF rows where pcd equals "AB106". For "AC200" DCF(mean), it is 1 (3/3), where the denominator is the number of rows starting with "AC2" and the numerator is the sum of DCF rows where pcd equals "AC200".

Comment: "AB106 DCF(mean) is equal to 0.333..." do you mean: "AB106 DCF(mean) is equal to 0.5..."?

Comment: Is this all csv, or tab delimited?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1

f = StringIO("""pcd DCF DDF FFD
AB106   1   2   1
AB107   2   3   2
AC200   2   4   5
AC200   1   6   6
AC201   2   3   1
SD234   3   1   3""")

df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t")

# start
print(df)
```

```
     pcd  DCF  DDF  FFD
0  AB106    1    2    1
1  AB107    2    3    2
2  AC200    2    4    5
3  AC200    1    6    6
4  AC201    2    3    1
5  SD234    3    1    3
```

```py
# assuming all other columns will be used as numerators
numerators = df.groupby("pcd").sum()

df["pcd3"] = df.pcd.str[:3]

df["denominators"] = df.groupby("pcd3").pcd.transform("count")

denominators = df.groupby("pcd").denominators.max()

out = numerators.div(denominators, axis="index")

out = out.add_suffix("(mean)")

out = out.reset_index()

print(out)
```

```
     pcd  DCF(mean)  DDF(mean)  FFD(mean)
0  AB106   0.500000   1.000000   0.500000
1  AB107   1.000000   1.500000   1.000000
2  AC200   1.000000   3.333333   3.666667
3  AC201   0.666667   1.000000   0.333333
4  SD234   3.000000   1.000000   3.000000
```

Comment: what if I have 50 columns. It's not feasible to write 50 lines of groupby. Is there any efficient way to solve this?

Comment: @nuke -- see edits